# Android adb logcat time filter

Tags: android, logging, filtering, adb, logcat

Does anyone know how to filter out the logcat ('adb shell logcat') so that it only shows the log statements after *current date and time* ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: After current date and time? So, like, logging *future* errors? That would be the best debugging tool *ever*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45422595/1778421

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Activities created after the current date and time?  Or just log statements after the current time?
Could it be as simple as "adb logcat -c; adb logcat"

Comment: Yup, my mistake, I meant log statements after the current time. I'm writing a java program that execute 'adb shell logcat' which I assume is the same as 'adb logcat'. When the program is stopped and restarted, the log displayed includes those from previous run. So I'm looking for a way to filter out the log statements from after the current time.

Comment: Never mind, "adb logcat -c; adb logcat" does it :) Thanks Stan!

Answer (score 7):

use

`adb logcat -t "01-21 10:10:10.000"`

this will give you log

> after 21st January 10.10.10.000

Comment: The result is the same to what we get with `adb logcat`.

Comment: What is ":10.000" at the end?

Comment: 10 is for seconds 000 after . is miliseconds

Answer (score 1):

Before you start up logcat first pass it the argument -c
In the terminal you would say

```
adb logcat -c
adb logcat
```

This would produce a fresh log.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
$ adb logcat -T 1
```

This will print the most recent line plus any new lines starting from now on (passing `-T 0` is invalid and will log a warning and default to `-T 1`).

Where `-T` (from `adb logcat --help`) is:

```
  -T <count>                  Print only the most recent <count> lines
                              (does not imply -d).
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. `logcat -c` is a bad workaround that has the undesirable side effect of clearing all previous logs from the device.