# Start dual-sim settings page in xamarin android.ui

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I want to launch the "dual sim settings" page from an android widget using xamarin android ui.
So far I'm able to launch (for an example) DisplaySettings with

```
var pN=Android.Provider.Settings.ActionDisplaySettings;
var launchInt=new Intent(pN);
launchInt.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
context.StartActivity(launchInt);
```

My phone offers dual sim settings. I can even add a widget for it on the home screen.
Further using the App "Shortcut Creator" I managed to create a shortcut and the information says:
Action: android.intent.action.Main
Flags: new_task, clear_top, receiver_foreground
Component: com.android.settings/.DualCardSettings

But I have no idea how to call / launch this page.

Comment: Hi, here is a similar discussion for reference .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305407/android-dual-sim-card-api

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but I neither want to mess with the tow sims nor do I need an API - I just want to open a specific settings page from my app. In this case dual sim - but in general this could be any which has no constant in Android.Provider.Settings

Comment: Okey , from Android document (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings) , `ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS`  maybe the best closest to the dual sim settings.

Comment: Sorry but this is not close - it is a submenu of Android.Provider.Settings.ActionWirelessSettings - so I would have to go back up to this page from the roaming - and then into the dual-sim I'm searching for. If want a close by I'd use Android.Provider.Settings.ActionWirelessSettings. But there must be a way to open dual-sim directly since "Shortcut creator" can do it also. It even lists dual-sim as a "predefined settings page".

Comment: Got it. However google not updating it in android document. I think this way can have a try, using adb shell to output log when entering dual-sim setting. Then this maybe can see what the package name is , so can use Intent to start package class directly.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds good - but I have no idea how to do this - could you please provide some instructions on how to do this?

Comment: First, need adb environment .(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570912/android-adb-logcat-time-filter ) Second using cmd code to log info when app running.When you enter `dual sim settings` page , you can see log activity name.(eg: wifi setting page,https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZb0l.png) .Last can start another activity(https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity). However , if `dual sim settings` is a activity. need google expose its activity name , then can intent to it, else can not .

Comment: So if no exposed by google , then can not do that , unless you using a customed android system with exposed activity.

Comment: What I got is:
07-18 08:09:55.681  1218  1229 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[com.android.settings.SHORTCUT] flg=0x14000000 hwFlg=0x10 cmp=com.android.settings/.DualCardSettings bnds=[852,1632][1060,1941]} from uid 10087
07-18 08:09:55.681  1218  1229 I ActivityManager: ActivityRecord info: ActivityInfo{65e8a5a com.android.settings.DualCardSettings}

Comment: Okey, `com.android.settings/.DualCardSettings` is the activity name , you can have a try with opening by this.

Comment: I thought action is ...action.MAIN and component is ...settings/.DualCardSettings.

Anyhow I have no idea how to write this in C#. Could you support me with a snippet please.

Comment: I have updated in answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 07-18 08:09:55.681 1218 1229 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[com.android.settings.SHORTCUT] flg=0x14000000 hwFlg=0x10 cmp=com.android.settings/.DualCardSettings bnds=[852,1632][1060,1941]} from uid 10087 07-18 08:09:55.681 1218 1229 I ActivityManager: ActivityRecord info: ActivityInfo{65e8a5a com.android.settings.DualCardSettings}

From shared log, package name is `com.android.settings`, `com.android.settings.DualCardSettings` is the activity name , if android exposed this activity, you can open it as follow way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMain);
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.DualCardSettings ");
intent.SetComponent(componentName);
StartActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in the case someone else has this (or a similar) problem I post my working code - Created with the help of @Junior Jiang - MSFT

```
private void StartDualCardSettings(Context pContext) {
        try {
            /*
             07-18 08:09:55.681 1218 1229 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[com.android.settings.SHORTCUT] flg=0x14000000 hwFlg=0x10 cmp=com.android.settings/.DualCardSettings bnds=[852,1632][1060,1941]} from uid 10087 
             07-18 08:09:55.681 1218 1229 I ActivityManager: ActivityRecord info: ActivityInfo{65e8a5a com.android.settings.DualCardSettings} 
            */

            var settingsIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
            settingsIntent.AddCategory("com.android.settings.SHORTCUT");
            settingsIntent.SetComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.DualCardSettings"));
            settingsIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            pContext.StartActivity(settingsIntent);
            return;

        }
        catch(Exception eX) {
            // Something went wrong :)
        }
    }
```

Thank you very much - works like a charm.